# Difference between updating a global variable in Javascript without or with a function

Tags: javascript, return

What is the difference between these two methods to update the value of a (global) variable in Javascript?

```
 var a = true;

 a = false; // UPDATING WITH FUNCTION/RETURNING
 console.log(a); // false

 var changeAndReturna = function(p) {
    p = false;
    console.log(p);
    return p;
 };


 changeAndReturna(a); // UPDATING WITH FUNCTION/RETURNING // false
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The primary difference is that your second example doesn't update `a` at all:

```js
var a = true;

var changeAndReturna = function(p) {
  p = false;
  console.log(p);
  return p;
};
changeAndReturna(a);
console.log(a); // still true
```

To update `a`, it would have to do this:

```
    a = changeAndReturna(a);
//  ^^^^
```

(Or, because `a` is global, assign to `a` within the function. Which is generally poor practice.)

The reason is that `a`, the variable, is not passed into the function; the *value* of `a` is determined, and then that *value* is passed into the function and received as `p`. You've then updated `p` (which has no effect whatsoever on `a`).

JavaScript is a purely *pass-by-value* language. That means that when you give a variable as an argument to a function:

```
var a = 42;
foo(a);
```

...the *value* of that variable (42) is passed to the function, not a reference to the variable where it came from. This is **always** true in JavaScript.

There are languages where (optionally) you can pass a *reference* to the variable instead (pass-by-reference), such as C++ or C#; in those languages you can then use that variable reference to change the value of the variable that was passed in. But JavaScript is purely pass-by-value.

(Yes, even with objects. The value is the object reference, not the object. An object reference is not a variable reference. JavaScript has object references. It does not have variable references. Pass-by-reference requires variable references.)

Comment: Thanks, @t-j-crowder, your explanation it's very clear and very helpful! But, so, why this example (https://codepen.io/aminta/pen/oevdgb) works?

Comment: @AmintaCode: What makes you think it does? The code is mostly nonsense. One thing it does though is change `scrollYAmount` to `255` because it's directly assigning to it (like my comment above *"...Or, because a is global, assign to a within the function. Which is generally poor practice...."*). But then the whole `changeMyVariable` function is pointless, just calling `console.log` directly would do the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Here, we are calling function by `pass by value` approach, so it won't change the value of `a`.

*See the comments in code*.

```js
var a = 1;

 a = 2; 
 console.log("a without func = "+ a); 
 
 var changeAndReturna = function(p) {
    p = 3;
    //a=3; //if you update the value here, first it search var 'a' inside the func, if it won't get any variable then search 'a' globally and assign the value 3 to 'a'.
    console.log("inside func = " + p);
    return p;
 };

//a= changeAndReturna(a); //here you can assign 'a' with return val of func
console.log("ruturn val of func = "+ changeAndReturna(a)); //here we are passing value as "pass by value" approach.

console.log("after func call, a = "+ a); // if you change the value of 'a' inside function or with return value then it will show the updated value.
```

Comment: The term is *pass-by-value*, not call-by-value.